# UITableViewController inside UIPopoverController top is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` being used as the content view controller inside of a `UIPopoverController`. Unfortunately the table view content is being cut off up top, I can try to scroll down really far and see it, although it bounces back to the top. Sort of like this:

```
Table view content starts up here (what I want in the middle of the popover)

    ---------------
    |  bottom     |
    |   of        |
    |   table     |
    |   view      |
    ---------------
```

Is there a reason my `tableView` is way above the fold on the `UIPopoverController`?

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you to set the UIPopoverController's `popoverContentSize` to accommodate its content view controller's view.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set contentSize of your popOverController

```
//Calculate how tall the view should be by multiplying 
//the individual row height by the total number of rows.
NSInteger rowsCount = [_colorNames count];
NSInteger singleRowHeight = [self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView 
    heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
NSInteger totalRowsHeight = rowsCount * singleRowHeight;

//Calculate how wide the view should be by finding how 
//wide each string is expected to be
CGFloat largestLabelWidth = 0;
for (NSString *colorName in _colorNames) {
    //Checks size of text using the default font for UITableViewCell's textLabel. 
    CGSize labelSize = [colorName sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
    if (labelSize.width > largestLabelWidth) {
        largestLabelWidth = labelSize.width;
    }
}

//Add a little padding to the width
CGFloat popoverWidth = largestLabelWidth + 100;

//Set the property to tell the popover container how big this view will be.
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverWidth, totalRowsHeight);
```

Copied from [Ray's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial), Which I am using for my app now :)